# C# error "The transaction is either not associated with the current connection or has been completed"

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions

I'm having an error with my C# app when using a new SQL connection:

> The transaction is either not associated with the current connection or has been completed

The code is working with existing other SQL connections, however when I add this new SQL connection `connection1`, it errors out.

```
var connection1 = new SqlConnection("Server=abc001.test.com;Connection Timeout=1000;Trusted_Connection=Yes; Database=testing;");
connection1.Open();

var invoices = connection1.Query<invoice>(Sql.GetStatement("GetInvoices"), commandTimeout: 60);

foreach (var invoice in invoices)
{
    var transaction = connection1.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        //blablabla
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        transaction.Rollback(); 
        throw (e); //HERE GOT AN ERROR "The transaction is either not associated with the current connection or has been completed"
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you `Commit` your transactions on succes??

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to add that in my code. Just added it now.

Comment: The code you have posted can't rise that error, I must assume that something you do on the "try" unbounds the transaction. Add a [complete, minimal, reproducible example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks you are correct. Something in the try did cause that error. Thanks much.

Comment: @ichachan can you post what you've found as an answer? It could help other people to solve similar problem.